# Imagick: open file from path, resize, save to folder

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to append several images together into one big image, but the first hurdle is actually just getting the image to open.

I am attempting to do the following:

1. Open image from path
2. Size it with the specified dimensions
3. Save it to the current folder

I have the following:

```
define('WIDTH',  600);
define('HEIGHT', 800);

$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImage('dress.jpg');
$img->writeImage('image1.png');
```

I can get the image to save, but I do not know where to add the `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` definitions?

I tried doing the following:

```
$img->newImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, $img);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImage('dress.jpg');

$img->resizeImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);

$img->writeImage('image1.png');
```

After "creating" an image resource with `new Imagick()` you are "working" in that resource. `readImage()` reads the image which is then present in the resource - after that you can resize the resource and write it out after the work is done.

See the documentation for more info [Imagick::resizeImage()](http://php.net/manual/de/imagick.resizeimage.php)

With `new Imagick(WIDTH, HEIGHT)` you create an image resource with an empty canvas of the given size.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. The image is still the same size as before.

Comment: Did you try the example from the manual page and appended the `FILTER` parameter? I've edited my answer for that change.

See this comment http://php.net/manual/de/imagick.resizeimage.php#77339

Comment: Update: You can now specify 0 for either height or width and it will resize proportionally to the other value you choose.